# Expo Secure Store and RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am new to react/mobile development and was wondering the best way to securely store a token. The official documentation points to expo secure store which i'm trying to now implement.

I am also using reduxtoolkits RTK Query for my API requests, my question is how do I retrieve my stored token value and use it in the prepare headers section to create a bearer token that can be used successfully in requests.

At the moment i am getting an object error:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Here is my code so far...

```
    const getToken = async (key) => {
      try {
         await SecureStore.getItemAsync(key).then(result=>  result);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error");
      }
    };`

``

RTK slice
```

```
baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ 
    baseUrl: 'http://example.com/api',
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      const token = getToken('userToken')
  
      // If we have a token set in state, let's assume that we should be passing it.
      if (token) {
        headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
      }
  
      return headers
    },
 }),
```

```
Where am i going wrong?
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you would need to await that async function and not try to send a promise as a header:

```js
baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ 
    baseUrl: 'http://example.com/api',
    prepareHeaders: async (headers, { getState }) => {
      const token = await getToken('userToken')
  
      // If we have a token set in state, let's assume that we should be passing it.
      if (token) {
        headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
      }
  
      return headers
    },
 }),
```

Comment: This now returns :  `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {status, originalStatus, data, error}). If you meant to render a 
collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: That is from one of your components. You are probably writing something like `{error}` somewhere - but `error` is not a string that can just be rendered, it's an object. Maybe `console.log` it to look at it and then decide what part of that to render.